# My LI buttons are "taller" in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I've got a nav menu that uses list items as buttons with a color bar at bottom of button. In most browsers, the color bar displays at bottom of button, inside the button. But on Mac Firefox, the color bar display at the bottom of the button, oustide the button. SO only on Mac Firefox, my buttons are much taller than they should be. Any suggestions on how to get these buttons display correctly in Firefox to match how they display shorter on other browsers?

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/CEXts/3/

```
 .nav > li {
padding: 0;
float: left;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(183,183,183,1) 50%, rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
border-right: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
border-left: 1px solid #929292;
width: 169px;
height: 45px;
border-top: 1px solid #797979;
border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
letter-spacing: -0.5px;
font-size: 14px;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #CCCCCC;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To be completely honest with you, I'm not sure why this is but if you remove the `height: 45px` from the `li` styling, everything looks fine.

Comment: that's so bizarre. tks @Evan!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the margin to 0 on

```
 .nav > li {
 margin: 0;
 }
```

Looks fine to me...

Comment: I assume you tried to say "That style already exists"  and yes, you have to add it to the other .nav > li  rules.

Comment: whatever ... :) And let me see, I didn't even notice other ones - good eye